# Read data from excel and Write to List

Tags: java, excel

I want to get data to `List` and display it.But out put display 4 times.
My `excel` file containing `4` data.
I want to get one record. My code is

```
public static List readDataFromExcel() throws IOException{
        String filename = "path";

        List sheetData = new ArrayList();

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {

            fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

                List data = new ArrayList();
                while (cells.hasNext()) {
                    XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();
                    String value=" ";
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) 
                    {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            value = BigDecimal.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()).toPlainString();
                            data.add(value);
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            value=cell.getStringCellValue();
                            data.add(value);
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                            value = " ".toString();
                            data.add(value);
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            value = Boolean.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue()).toString();
                            data.add(value);
                            break;
                    }

                    sheetData.add(data);

                }

                fis.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return sheetData;
    }
```

Main methods

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    List serverdetailsList = ReadDataFromExcel.readDataFromExcel();
    List oneserverdetailsList = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < serverdetailsList.size(); i++) {

            System.out.println(serverdetailsList.get(i));

        }

    }
```

Out put image
[image]

Excel ScrenShot
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are adding the inner ArrayList(data) to the main arrayList (sheetdata) as many as the number of times you find a cell.

The approach should have been

```
 while (rows.hasNext()) {
            XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

            List data = new ArrayList();       
   while (cells.hasNext()) {
                XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();
                String value=" ";
                switch (cell.getCellType()) 
                {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                      value =                BigDecimal.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()).toPlainString();
                        data.add(value);
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        value=cell.getStringCellValue();
                        data.add(value);
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                        value = " ".toString();
                        data.add(value);
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        value = Boolean.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue()).toString();
                        data.add(value);
                        break;
                }

                //sheetData.add(data);

            }
       sheetData.add(data);
      fis.close();
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help
And also I want one element in a array 
for examples `[OS1, 10.23.14.25, 12.0, wradadasda]` I want` OS1`
How Can i get it

Comment: Can u please post a screenshot of ur excel?TIA

Comment: if you want the element whose 0th element is OS1 you can loop through the list and get it

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 for each loops

```
for(ArrayList innerList :serverdetailsList)
{for(Object cellData:innerList )
{
 if(cellData.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("OS1")){
 //Your operation 
 }
 }
 }
```

Hope this is what you are looking for!!